# Readin newly appended data only in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, web-scraping

I have a text file that gets appended with new data every 5 minutes. Is there any possible way using javascript that I can fetch only the data which is appended. Since data is appended at the end of the file and reading it again from starting is time-consuming. Is there any npm module which can read the file from the last line towards starting of data?

Comment: Are you running a php webserver on your machine?

Comment: At first - try with terminal with `php your_script.php` command. Later when you will accommodate to terminal - proceed installing free web server (such as Apache) and put your php script in /var/www/html and open it with browser `localhost/your_script.php` URL.